# htaccess, Redirect all requests to https://www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using .htaccess, I need to redirect all requests from

```
http://www.domain,
http://domain,
https://domain
```

to;

```
https://www.domain.com
```

How would I do this?
I don't have any subdomains.

Comment: hi. First of all you would ask that in the right place. And that's over at ServerFault. Just voted to migrate the question. And mod_rewrite can do all kinds of fancy things, but what does non-www refer to? Only domain.com or also other.domain.com?

Comment: non www refers to (http://domain.com). There is no subdomains on this site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That will direct all HTTP requests to https://www.example.com as well as redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com.

Comment: How would that be written without hard coding the domain?

Comment: Perfect. Works a treat for redirecting all urls to https://www. Thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```