# .HTACESS redirection not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect, hubspot

I just like to redirect my website example.com to https://www.example.com

**But the scenario is:**

1. I don't have SSL at my root domain **i.e. example.com**
2. My website is CMS based website and cname is created at www.
3. www is a cname for CMS and pointing to my website and CMS have its
   own ssl i.e. https://www.example.com
4. I am using SSL of CMS and not domain provider.

Now, what all i have to do is to redirect all possible URL's to https://www.example.com.

I did redirection using .htaccess and all are working fine except one.

example.com --- **Working Fine**

http://example.com/ --- **Working Fine**

***https://example.com/ --- Not Working Fine***

https://www.example.com/ --- **Working Fine**

http://www.example.com/ --- **Working Fine**

Do not know why? Here is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect to domain with www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Same for HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Can somebody help me in this? I want to redirect all my URL to https://www.example.com

Note: If i take SSL at my root domain too from domain providers then its throwing **incorrect certificate name error**.

We are sing 1&1 hosting services and CMS is Hubspot.

Comment: see if [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085740/htaccess-redirect-all-requests-to-https-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085740/htaccess-redirect-all-requests-to-https-www) can help

Comment: Not working for me :(

Comment: are you obliged to do this with .htaccess? can't you use Redirect in conf file?

Comment: @Andra, We want SEO friendly redirection. No matters, its done through .htaccess or by conf file. Please note, we are using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

First redirect from non-www to www and then redirect from HTTP to HTTPS:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```