# How does it work under the table if I put google.com on the browser?

Tags: html, url, dns

It is not the question like "what happens if I input an URL on a browser".
My point it, to be specifically, if I input www.google.com or google.com or https://google.com or http://google.com on a browser, the URL will be automatically changed to https://www.google.com and load the html content. What is the reason?

Comment: Dude! It's not the DNS, it's the program inside https://google.com, when requested, makes sure it goes to the right URL: https://www.google.com. It's canonical.

Comment: You are welcome boss. `:D`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some URLs called canonical URLs. It's clearly given, why a website should be [consolidating duplicate URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066) in Google. So, for the same reason, the web application will be written in such a way, say, take my website: https://praveen.science/, I personally coded this way:

```
<?php
  if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]" != "https://praveen.science/") {
    header("Location: https://praveen.science/");
    die();
  }
?>
```

No matter what URL you put, it always goes to https://praveen.science/. This is the "under the hood" reason. Try out the following variations:

- http://praveen.science/
- https://praveen.science/
- http://www.praveen.science/
- https://www.praveen.science/

All the above URLs will just go to https://praveen.science/ because of the code above. And that's a live code from my website. **It's not DNS, but just the individual application routing configuration.** This helps the search engine and other places to avoid duplicate URLs.

The other way to implement this is using `.htaccess`. (Example: [htaccess, Redirect all requests to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085740/htaccess-redirect-all-requests-to-https-www) (Random Question on Stack Overflow)).

This is important to have your users or requests to be unanimously routed to one single URL. You can read about why this is implemented in many websites here:

- [Duplicate Content](https://moz.com/learn/seo/duplicate-content)
- [Consolidate duplicate URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066)

Another way to answer your question will include checking the request data. When you give a request to any of the URLs other than https://www.google.com/, the response will be a HTTP 301 Moved Permanently:

[image: request]

This is one way of having all the requests routed to one single domain (or path) and making sure there are no duplicates.

Comment: Besides HTTP redirections that happen after connecting to some resource, have a look also at HTTP Strict Transport Security, that could make a browser do an HTTPS query automatically instead of an HTTP one. Various sites are also preloaded in some browsers, see https://hstspreload.org/ and https://hstspreload.com/

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Yep. That works too! `:)` Thanks for the addition.