# What is the correct htaccess redirection code?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I used this code on htaccess to redirect the website all versions of URLs to `https://www`, but some tools show redirect chain errors. Is anyone solve this issue?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Does the SSL certificate you are using support www.domain.com as well as just domain.com (does it support both with www. and without)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [htaccess, Redirect all requests to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085740/htaccess-redirect-all-requests-to-https-www)

Answer (score 0):

With your current directives, if you request `http://www.example.com/`, it will redirect to `https://www.www.example.com/` - which is obviously not the intention.

You need to modify the capturing 3rd condition to exclude the optional `www.` subdomain.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

> but some tools show redirect chain errors

Regardless of what "some tools" show, what is important is what your site reports.

Comment: All redirection are work properly but audit tools show redirect warning, redirect chain issues

Comment: And the directive I posted above resolves that "redirect chain issue"?

Comment: This code redirects properly on https:www.domain.com/. I want to know why the MOZ audit SEO tool shows the redirect chain warning. 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: MOZ Tool suggest This for redirect chain error:

Redirect chains are often caused when multiple redirect rules pile up, such as redirecting a “www” to “non-www” URL or a non-secure page to a secure/HTTPS page. Look for any recurring chains that could be rewritten as a single rule.

Comment: The code you posted in your comment is the same as posted in your question, not the updated code from my answer?! The code in your question is incorrect and certainly will result in a redirect chain under certain conditions. (?) However, you don't need additional tools in order to diagnose redirect chains... open the developer tools in your browser and look at the _network traffic_. From there you can monitor precisely what redirect chain you are seeing (which is required for further diagnosis). There may be a conflict with your application logic?